# What does the operator |= do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I found the following code in a JS project:

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = 0;
for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
  a[0] |= b; 
}
```

What does the `|=` do in the body of the for loop?

The code example is dubious, but has been presented [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/#toc-topic-numbers) by V8 for an example of improved performance.

**Updated Example**

The above example is equivalent to `var a = [15];` for most intents and purposes.  A more realistic example for the `|=` operator would be to set up binary flags in a single variable, for example on a permission object:

```
//Set up permission masks
var PERMISSION_1_MASK = parseInt('0001',2);
var PERMISSION_2_MASK = parseInt('0010',2);
..

//Set up permissions
userPermissions = 0;
userPermissions |= hasPermissionOne && PERMISSION_1_MASK;
userPermissions |= hasPermissionTwo && PERMISSION_2_MASK;
..

//Use permissions
if(userPermissions & PERMISSION_1_MASK){
    ..//Do stuff only allowed by permission 1
}
```

Comment: I just realize that the code it's from here. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/

Comment: @razpeitia read the question and you'll find that URL...

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
a[0] |= b
```

is basically

```
a[0] = a[0] | b
```

"|" is an [or bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

**Update**
When `a[0]` is assigned `0`, `a[0]` in binary is `0000`. In the loop,

1. b = 0

   ```
   a[0] = 0 (base 10) = 0000 (base 2)
   b    = 0 (base 10) = 0000 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0000 (base 2) = 0 (base 10)
   ```
2. b = 1

   ```
   a[0] = 0 (base 10) = 0000 (base 2)
   b    = 1 (base 10) = 0001 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0001 (base 2) = 1 (base 10)
   ```
3. b = 2

   ```
   a[0] = 1 (base 10) = 0001 (base 2)
   b    = 2 (base 10) = 0010 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0011 (base 2) = 3 (base 10)
   ```
4. b = 3

   ```
   a[0] = 3 (base 10) = 0011 (base 2)
   b    = 3 (base 10) = 0011 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0011 (base 2) = 3 (base 10)
   ```
5. b = 4

   ```
   a[0] = 3 (base 10) = 0011 (base 2)
   b    = 4 (base 10) = 0100 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0111 (base 2) = 7 (base 10)
   ```
6. b = 5

   ```
   a[0] = 7 (base 10) = 0111 (base 2)
   b    = 5 (base 10) = 0101 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0111 (base 2) = 7 (base 10)
   ```
7. b = 6

   ```
   a[0] = 7 (base 10) = 0111 (base 2)
   b    = 6 (base 10) = 0110 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0111 (base 2) = 7 (base 10)
   ```
8. b = 7

   ```
   a[0] = 7 (base 10) = 0111 (base 2)
   b    = 7 (base 10) = 0111 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 0111 (base 2) = 7 (base 10)
   ```
9. b = 8

   ```
   a[0] = 7 (base 10) = 0111 (base 2)
   b    = 8 (base 10) = 1000 (base 2)
                      ---------------
   a[0] | b           = 1111 (base 2) = 15 (base 10)
   ```
10. b = 9

    ```
    a[0] = 15 (base 10) = 1111 (base 2)
    b    =  9 (base 10) = 1001 (base 2)
                        ---------------
    a[0] | b            = 1111 (base 2) = 15 (base 10)
    ```

At the end of the loop the value of `a[0]` is `15`

Comment: @user1638092 glad to be of help :)

Comment: And just to make it explicit, steps 4, 6, 7, 8, and 10 are all redundant, so this loop is a bad example of performance gains...

Answer (score 53):

```
x |= y;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x | y;
```

where `|` stands for *bitwise OR*.

Comment: Is there an idiomatic meaning? Or some trick, like when you floor down floats with `~~`?

Comment: @katspaugh There is. For example it can be used for efficient encoding and checking for privileges ( this would fit with OP code as well ). Read [this article](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/create-permissions-using-bitwise-operators-in-php/).

Comment: @katspaugh what did u mean by "floor down floats with ~~"? I have never heard of such a thing!

Answer (score 11):

As with most assignment operators, it is equivalent to applying the operator using the lefthand value again:

```
a |= b
a = a | b
```

Just like

```
a += b
a = a + b
```

Look on [Moz Dev Net](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) for more.

[Edit: Brain fail, mixed up | and ||. Need more coffee. Modified below]

Since `|` is the Bitwise OR operator, the result of `a|b` will be the integer representing the bitstring with all the 1 bits of `a` and `b`. Note that javascript has no native int or bitstring types, so it will first cast `a` and `b` to int, then do a bitwise OR on the bits. So 9 | 2 in binary is 1001 | 0010 = 1011, which is 11, but 8|2 = 8.

The effect is to add the flag bits of `b` into `a`. So if you have some flag `WEEVILFLAG=parseInt(00001000,2)` :

```
// a = parseInt(01100001,2)
if(isWeevilish(a))
    a |= WEEVILFLAG;
// now a = parseInt(01101001,2)
```

will set that bit to 1 in a.

Comment: So this is the same as the logical or? Eg. var a = "title" || x

Comment: You are confusing logical OR and bitwise OR.

Comment: Bah. Bitwise OR not logical OR. Brains are funny things. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are ones.

Code:
    result = a | b;

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator, which returns a one for each position where one (not both) of the corresponding bits of its operands is a one. The next example returns 4 (0100):