# Why does this log output show the same answer in each iteration?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrong value in console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214430/wrong-value-in-console-log)
>   [What |= does in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854644/what-does-in-javascript)

OK, I was [reading an article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/) on optimising JS for Googles V8 engine, when i saw this code example...

I nearly skimmed over it, but then I saw this; |=; **a[0] |= b;**

```
a = new Array();
a[0] = 0;
for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
  console.log(a, b)
  a[0] |= b;  // Much better! 2x faster.
}
```

a[0] |= b;

So I ran it, in my console, with a console.log in the loop and resulted in 15;

```
[15] 0
[15] 1
[15] 2
[15] 3
[15] 4
[15] 5
[15] 6
[15] 7
[15] 8
[15] 9
```

WHAT?!?! Where the hell does it get 15 from, on every iteration?!?!?!

I've been a web dev for 7 years, and this has stumped me and a fellow colleague.

Can somebody talk me through this code?

Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854644/what-does-in-javascript

Comment: @vimalnath I thought someone else had asked the same ruddy question this morning!

Comment: the question is poorly written, but it's not really about `|=` - it's about the behaviour of `console.log()`.  Please don't close it!

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah, Your answer is the right on for this question

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214430/wrong-value-in-console-log/11214508#11214508) about the part that isn't a duplicate from a few minutes ago.

Comment: @dystroy I'll point at that question and then send the final close vote...

Comment: OP, I suggest to accept Alnitak's answer, and things will be as clean as they can be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is bitwise OR
[more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 2):

The reason it shows `[15]` in every iteration is because `console.log()` output is buffered, and objects or arrays passed to it are not evaluated immediately.

Your loop calculates `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9`, which is 15.

By the time `console.log()` gets around to calling `a.toString()` the loop already finsihed, and so it shows that final result of 15, rather than the intermediate results.

If you had logged `a[0]` rather than `a` each time you would have seen the real result, because primitive values are evaluated immediately:

```
a = new Array();
a[0] = 0;
for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
  console.log(a[0], b)
  a[0] |= b;  // Much better! 2x faster.
}

0 0
0 1
1 2
3 3
3 4
7 5
7 6
7 7
7 8
15 9
```

Comment: Yes, I verified that : http://jsfiddle.net/S3cE9/ (I was about to answer the same thing)

Comment: @dystroy please upvote - the rest of the answers have misread the question (although to be fair it was poorly written)

Comment: +1 done ([self promoting link included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214430/wrong-value-in-console-log/11214508#11214508))

Comment: +1 for the right answer to the question

Comment: Ok yeh, thats wrong, but doesn't anwer the question, what is |= and what does it do...

Comment: Ok, I see the confuion, the question got renamed?!?! I Originally called 
"What |= does in JavaScript?"
I don't know who changed it to "Why does this log output show the same answer in each iteration?"

Comment: @WillHancock I changed the question title, because the _real_ question was your line _"Where the hell does it get 15 from, on every iteration?"_, which is explained by the `console.log()` behaviour, and not _really_ how `|=` works, which should be obvious to a webdev with your experience ;-)

Comment: p.s. your downvote it not appreciated.  Mine was the only answer to address your real point of confusion (i.e. why the answer was apparently 15 every time).

Answer (score 0):

```
  a[0] |= b; 

is equal to

  a[0] =  a[0]| b;  //bit wise operation
```