# Javascript |= operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, operator-keyword

I've seen the operator `|=` in a jQuery plugin, in the following line:

```
if (e.ctrlKey) mod |= 1;
```

How it works?
Is it a good practice to use it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/81bads72%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: A good place to start is the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Bitwise_OR_assignment) :)

Comment: Bitwise OR operator. Looks like shorthand for `mod = mod | 1`

Comment: Look at all these reference links...wow what a little bit of searching turns up. Try a little bit of research before asking

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12854644/211627

Answer (score 1):

The `|` operator is a [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). It essentially performs a logical OR operation on corresponding pairs of bits in its arguments. If any bit is `1`, the resulting bit is also `1`. E.g.:

```
  00101
| 10100
= 10101
```

`a |= b` is simply shorthand for `a = a | b`, similar to several other binary operators in JavaScript.

It is often useful for setting [binary configuration flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).